# Transform XML with XSLT through input textarea

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform XML using XSLT, for that purpose I want the XML text to be inputed using a textarea and the result of the transformation to be shown in other textarea.
My JavaScript code until now is the following one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var xslTransform = new XslTransform("XSLTCode.xsl");

        function transformarXML(){
            var xmlIn = document.getElementById("XMLIN").value;
            var xmlOut = document.getElementById("XMLOUT");

            var outputText = xslTransform.transform(xmlIn);

            xmlOut.value = outputText;

        }

</script>
```

But for some reason the output textarea don't show any text at all. How should I do it correctly with JavaScript? Is there any other easier solution that I haven't thought about?

Comment: If that is Javascript inside the browser then consider to make use of the code snippet feature of Stackoverflow to show in your question a minimal but complete and executable code snippet allowing others to reproduce the problem. No browser I know provides an `XslTransform` object you seem to be using in `new XslTransform("XSLTCode.xsl");` so we obviously would need to see the code implementing that. And the snippet you have shown shows a functions `transformarXML` but does not call it, so if that is all your code then it won't do anything, you would need to call the function somewhere.

Comment: This is Javascript inside the browser, so as you say, Javascript inside the browser doesn't have `XslTransform` provided? Is there another class or solution to replace the `XslTransform` in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For browsers other than IE you can use XSLTProcessor to perform the XSLT transformation and DOMParser to parse the XML respectively XSLT string input into documents.

```js
function transform(xml, xslt) {
  var domParser = new DOMParser();
  var sheet = domParser.parseFromString(xslt, 'application/xml');
  var doc = domParser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
  var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
  proc.importStylesheet(sheet);
  var resultDoc = proc.transformToDocument(doc);
  // depending on the kind of result created or wanted it might be better to use return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc)
  return resultDoc.documentElement.outerHTML;
}

async function loadAndTransform(xml, xsltUrl) {
  try {
    var response = await fetch(xsltUrl);
    var xsltCode = await response.text();
    return transform(xml, xsltCode);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
}

async function handler1() {
  document.getElementById('result').value = await loadAndTransform(document.getElementById('input-xml').value, 'data:application/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('xslt').value));
}

async function handler2() {
  document.getElementById('result').value = await loadAndTransform(document.getElementById('input-xml').value, 'sheet.xsl');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input-xml" rows="10" cols="80"><root>
  <list>
     <item>a</item>
     <item>b</item>
  </list>
</root>
</textarea>

<textarea id="xslt" rows="10" cols="80">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
     <html>
       <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </body>
     </html>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="list">
     <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </ul>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="item">
     <li>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</textarea>

<input type="button" value="transform"
  onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = transform(document.getElementById('input-xml').value, document.getElementById('xslt').value);">
  
<input type="button" value="load and transform"
  onclick="handler1();">
  
<!--
<input type="button" value="load and transform from url"
  onclick="handler2();">
-->
  
<textarea id="result" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Note that XSLTProcessor is mainly meant to be used to create DOM nodes to be further used, if you want to have the result as a string you need to serialize the DOM node, in the snippet I have used outerHTML for HTML and also mentioned new XMLSerializer() if you want XML output.

Comment: And how could I add in `importStylesheet()` the XSLT as a local file? I mean something like `importStylesheet"XSLTCode.xsl")`

Comment: What is the file "local" to? Is it on the same web server as the HTML document with the Javascript? Or is the HTML document loaded from the file system? In general you load XML documents with XMLHttpRequest but there are the usual browser specific security restrictions on where you can load from (same origin policy might only allow loading files from the same origin the HTML document comes from, local file system access might be restricted in browsers like Chrome).

Comment: @DavidGodoy, I have edited the code snippet to indicate one (new) way with client-side Javascript in up-to-date versions of Edge, Chrome and Firefox to fetch the XSLT from a URL as text and then use the same function as before to run the transformation and show the result in a textarea (`document.getElementById('result').value = await loadAndTransform(document.getElementById('input-xml').value, 'sheet.xsl');`)